# Firebase in app messages going missing for new users

Tags: firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

we are using Firebase in app messaging on iOS and Android, targeted on an imported segment of firebase tokens. However, its not clear from the documentation what is supposed to happen if the segment is updated and re-imported with new users. Does anyone know if new users in the updated segment are sent a message from an already running campaign or would you have to re-publish to get those users?

A related question, (and this might be the reason we are not getting messages to new users). We set FireInApMessanging.messageDisplaySuppressed to true for new users until they have finished the onboarding process. If a message is delivered in this time, does the message get thrown away forever or should it get though once the flag has been set to false and the triggering event is fired again (in our case on_foreground)

It seems like one of these two problems is causing us to lose messages. The only way to fix is to re-publish the campaign, but this has the problem of the same users getting the message twice. Is there another way to suppress this, other than manually finding out which tokens have already seen the message and removing them from the segment?

We are using "Once per device for this campaign" and no end date

Thank you

Martin.